# Error with Sci-Kit Learn SGD Algo - "Array contains NaN or infinity"

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nan

I am getting an error stating "Array contains NaN or infinity". I have checked my data both train/test for missing values and there is nothing missing.

It's possible I have the wrong interpretation of what "Array contains NaN or infinity" means.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\training.csv','r'), delimiter=',')[0:50]    
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:50] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\test.csv','r'), delimiter=',')[0:50]

    #create and train the SGD
    sgd = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
    sgd.fit(train, target)
    predictions = [x[1] for x in sgd.predict(test)]

    savetxt('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\preds.csv', predictions, delimiter=',', fmt='%f')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I thought that the data type might be throwing the algo for a loop (they are floating-points).

I know that SGD can handle floating-points so I am not sure if this setup is requiring me to declare the datatype.

Such as one of the following:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype('i4')   # 32-bit signed integer
>>> dt = np.dtype('f8')   # 64-bit floating-point number
>>> dt = np.dtype('c16')  # 128-bit complex floating-point number
>>> dt = np.dtype('a25')  # 25-character string
```

Below is the full error-message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-af5537e7802b> in <module>()
     19
     20 if __name__=="__main__":
---> 21     main()

<ipython-input-62-af5537e7802b> in main()
     13     #create and train the SGD
     14     sgd = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
---> 15     sgd.fit(train, target)
     16     predictions = [x[1] for x in sgd.predict(test)]
     17

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.pyc in fi
t(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, class_weight, sample_weight)
    518                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_i
nit,
    519                          class_weight=class_weight,
--> 520                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    521
    522

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.pyc in _f
it(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, class_w
eight, sample_weight)
    397             self.class_weight = class_weight
    398
--> 399         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    400         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    401

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in atleast2d_or_csr(X
, dtype, order, copy)
    114     """
    115     return _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse.csr_matrix
,
--> 116                                 "tocsr")
    117
    118

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in _atleast2d_or_spar
se(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse_class, convmethod)
     94         _assert_all_finite(X.data)
     95     else:
---> 96         X = array2d(X, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
     97         _assert_all_finite(X)
     98     return X

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype,
order, copy)
     79                         'is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to dens
e.')
     80     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
---> 81     _assert_all_finite(X_2d)
     82     if X is X_2d and copy:
     83         X_2d = safe_copy(X_2d)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite
(X)
     16     if (X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.s
um())
     17             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
---> 18         raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
     19
     20

ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error, and `print dataset.dtype`? Also, you have a comment saying that you're "skipping the header row with `[1:]`", but you don't seem to be doing so....

Comment: Looks to me like @Dougal has a good suggestion about loading the header. You might try testing whether your dataset loaded properly with `assert not np.any(np.isnan(dataset) | np.isinf(dataset))`.

Comment: did you try     numpy.nan_to_num(ndarray)  that function makes the nans to zero and the infinitys to large numbers as far as i know, (useful if you know what result you should get on zero and very high numbers, otherwise not really)

Comment: @lmjohns3: or `np.all(np.isfinite(dataset))`, which is effectively what scikit-learn is doing in its input validation.

Comment: if you have a single zero u will get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error reports you have either `np.nan` or `np.inf` or `-np.inf` somewhere in your data. Since you're reading from a text file and you say your *data* does not contain missing values, this is likely either caused by column headers or some other value in the file that cannot be automatically interpreted.

The documentation for `genfromtxt` shows that the default `dtype` for read-in arrays is `float`, meaning that all values that you read must pass the equivalent of `float(x)`.

If you are unsure if this is causing the error you can remove non-finite numbers from a numpy array as follows:

```
dataset[ ~np.isfinite(dataset) ] = 0  # Set non-finite (nan, inf, -inf) to zero
```

If that eliminates the error, you can be sure that you have invalid values in your variable, *somewhere*. To find *where* you can use the following:

```
np.where(~np.isfinite(dataset))
```

This will return a list of indices where the invalid values are, e.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> dataset = np.array([[0,1,1],[np.nan,0,0],[1,2,np.inf]])
>>> dataset
array([[  0.,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,   0.,   0.],
       [  1.,   2.,  inf]])

>>> np.where(~np.isfinite(dataset))
(array([1, 2]), array([0, 2]))
```